# Rails has_many with `through` option "loses" joins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, has-many-through

I have the following example model structure:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts

  scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :visible_posts, -> { joins(:category).merge(Category.active) }, class: Post
  has_many :visible_posts_comments, through: :visible_posts, source: :comments

  has_many :comments
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now a `User.first.visible_posts_comments` raises the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "categories"
LINE 1: ..." = "posts"."id" WHERE "posts"."user_id" = $1 AND "categorie...
```

Which is because the SQL which is executed by this association is the following:

```
2.1.2 :009 > u.visible_posts_comments.to_sql
 => "SELECT \"comments\".* FROM \"comments\" INNER JOIN \"posts\" ON \"comments\".\"post_id\" = \"posts\".\"id\" WHERE \"posts\".\"user_id\" = $1 AND \"categories\".\"active\" = 't'"
```

While `visible_posts` works properly by adding the `INNER JOIN` on `categories`,

```
2.1.2 :010 > u.visible_posts.to_sql
 => "SELECT \"posts\".* FROM \"posts\" INNER JOIN \"categories\" ON \"categories\".\"id\" = \"posts\".\"category_id\" WHERE \"posts\".\"user_id\" = $1 AND \"categories\".\"active\" = 't'"
```

why does `visible_posts_comments` seem to "lose" the `joins(:category)` statement but keeps the `merge(Category.active)`? I see no reason to drop the joins of the `through`-association on purpose. Is this a bug or a feature?

I am using activerecord-4.1.8.

Could be related to this: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17904

Comment: Does it also happen if the query uses `includes` instead of `joins`?

Comment: @fjuan  changed     joins into     includes and visible_posts also raised the same error     missing FROM-clause

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've created a rails project the same as yours, found the same issue.
Two points on this issue:

#### 1. has_many :through  will delete "joins" from the through relations, source code:

```
#lib/active_record/associations/through_association.rb  line 14
    def target_scope
      scope = super
      chain.drop(1).each do |reflection|
        relation = reflection.klass.all
        relation.merge!(reflection.scope) if reflection.scope

        scope.merge!(
          relation.except(:select, :create_with, :includes, :preload, :joins, :eager_load)
        )

      end
      scope
    end
```

I think the reason they did like this is a consideration of record creating operations.  ex. Maybe u.visible_posts_comments.create(...) will make ActiveRecord confused

#### 2. A walkaround way for you:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :visible_posts, -> { merge(Post.active) }, class: Post
  has_many :visible_posts_comments, -> { joins(:post).merge(Post.active) }, class: Comment

  has_many :comments
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments

  scope :active, -> { joins(:category).merge(Category.active) }
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: I accept the answer because it's in the code of ActiveRecord, though I still don't get why they did that. Calling `has_many_through_association.create(...)` does not make much sense to me at all because it would never be clear which of the (possibly many) "through" records the created one should be assigned to.